# How to get return value of curl in a variable

Tags: php

i have two pages.
get.php is

```
<?php
echo "Hello";

?>
```

and set.php is

```
   <?php
$ch = curl_init();
//echo "1";
// set URL and other appropriate options
$ht=curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/vishwas/get.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$a=curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

echo $a;
?>
```

I get output is Hello1 . but i want only Hello in variable $a, means get output of the url in a variable.

Comment: Use this option to curl_setopt():
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

Comment: Thank you so much, its working fine..tha was a big help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For return output form curl you set curl_setopt()

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)
```